# Vim: How can I create a file after "$ vim file.tgz"?

Tags: vim, tar

I want to create a file to tarball, without explicitly opening/extracting it but directly by using Vim. Is that possible?

```
$ vim file.tgz
:e someNewfile
:w!    # how can I create here a file?
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question: Do you want to add a new file into an existing tar archive?

Comment: In general, you should differentiate between uncompressed tars (tape archives) and compressed tars, as they are fundamentally different. With an uncompressed tar, you *can* do pretty much anything you want, such as 'append' a new file in the tar, then vi it. Compressed tars, on the other hand, are unreasonable creations. Just tar it, then compress it (gzip `tar -c your-tar.tar folder` to `your-tar.tar.gz`).  And then solve for the modification problem in uncompressed tars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim handles tar and derived files (including .tgz) using a vimscript called `tar.vim`.  You can see `tar.vim`'s documentation by typing `:help tar<CR>` inside vim.  According to that documentation:

> When one edits a *.tar file, this plugin will handle displaying a
>   contents page.  Select a file to edit by moving the cursor atop the
>   desired file, then hit the `<return>` key.  After editing, one may also
>   write to the file.
>   **Currently, one may not make a new file in tar archives via the plugin.**

So you can edit a file which is already in the tar, but you cannot currently add new files using a vanilla setup of vim.

Comment: Does this work for gzipped tarballs? 'Cause that's what I tried, and also what the OP asked. When I tried it (on linux) it didn't work.

Comment: Interesting.  It *does* work for me on OSX, using vanilla vim installed via homebrew and no other addons.  Maybe your linux distribution's vim package doesn't include the tar.vim script?  For me, the script is located in /usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/tar.vim.  If your distribution doesn't have it by default, you can get tar.vim manually from here:  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=522

Comment: Well, colour me silly, I just tested again, starting with raw .tar, then .tar.gz and finally .tgz and, guess what, it worked. I must have done something slightly mad yesterday :)