# Vim - editing tar and tgz files

Tags: vim, tar

I'm embarrassed to say, after a couple of decades of using vim, I've only just discovered you can open, browse, and look at tar, and tgz files in vim (although in fairness, I think that this is quite a recent add-on)

(*if you haven't discovered this feature yet by the way, it's very cool*)

Does anyone know if one can **edit** files the files in tar files, and have vim repack them back into the archive.

[The plugin page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=522) and [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873716/vim-how-can-i-create-a-file-after-vim-file-tgz) Seems to suggest it's read only, but I wondered if there was a way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, we are on the same page on that :-) I would create a script for that, I doubt vim supports that by default. But history shows we can be wrong :-)

Comment: I just tried it, and it works. :-)

Answer (score 4):

just tried this at work and it actually works - perhaps I had an older version of VIM at home.

Comment: It looks like the gzip plugin ships with version 6 (`:h new-plugins`) so I imagine you had an older version of vim or it was not built with plugin support like a the tiny build of vim. See `:h :version` for more information